# Example of a non empty set with no order relation on it

Tags: order-theory

Is there an example on which you cannot define any order relation ?

Any order relation means neither total order or partial order.

Comment: The empty set is an example.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Isn't the empty set vacuously ordered, as in, the empty set is a total ordering relation for the empty set? At any rate, for a non-empty set, there is always the trivial partial order, where elements may only be compared to themselves. The axioms of ZF allow the construction of such an order.

Answer (score 3):

Any set can be given a partial order.  Indeed, the relation $=$ is a partial order on any set.

Any set can also be given a total order, but this is much harder to prove, and in fact requires the axiom of choice.  Indeed, the axiom of choice is known to be equivalent to the statement that every set can be given a *well order*, which is a special kind of total order.  The statement that every set can be given a total order can thus be considered a weak form of the axiom of choice.  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37272/are-all-sets-totally-ordered for some discussion.

Comment: Are you sure the axiom of choice is required for a total order? I know it's required for a well-order, but a total order is a lot weaker.